# LiveUSB stuck after "Probing EDD" during boot

Tags: arch-linux, boot, system-installation, thinkpad

I am trying to install Arch Linux on a brand new Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon 4th. When I start from my LiveUSB image, it gets stuck right after the following line (which is the first line of the screen):

> Probing EDD (edd=off to disable)... ok

I created my LiveUSB stick from OSX with `dd` like in the documentation from Arch Linux ([here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media#In_Mac_OS_X))

It seems like the "Probing EDD" is not the problem, since it says "ok". How can I know what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add `intel_pstate=no_hwp` to the kernel parameters. I did it by pressing [Tab] in the bootloader.

I found the solution [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180126112338/http://forum.projektneptun.ch/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=7470&sid=b568842e2e25148d6ab61e8bfa3664b0).

Comment: This doesn't work with me. Windows 10.0.19042, Virtual Box 6.1.18, archlinux 2021-03-01.

Answer (score 2):

That is one way but what I did was:

1. Click settings before starting the VM
2. Goto to System
3. Look at Extended Features
4. Click "Enable I/O APIC"

Note: This only works for a VM sorry

It solves it but I don't know what the effects are.

Comment: This is only for a VM

Comment: This doesn't work with me. Windows 10.0.19042, Virtual Box 6.1.18, archlinux 2021-03-01. The I/IO APIC feature is switched on by default if you add multiple virtual cores.