# “Probing EDD” error when booting a live OS from a USB drive

Tags: boot, kali-linux, system-installation, live-usb, macintosh

I'm trying to boot into a Kali Linux live thumb drive on my Mid-2012 MacBook Pro, to partition a secondary internal hdd that has Windows (set up with bootcamp) on it (to install Kali in the new partition).

I created the bootable drive by following the instructions from [Dual Boot Kali on Mac Hardware](https://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-dual-boot-on-mac-hardware).

It works at the start, and I chose to boot into Live (amd64)
[image: When I boot into the thumb drive]
Then, it takes a super long time on this screen (sorry for the blurriness)[image]and then just goes to a blank screen.[image: Blank screen]

Is there anything more that I need to do to boot from this? Or should I just wait and maybe it'll boot.

(I used `dd`to create the bootable drive from an iso)

Comment: Can you change TTY's? How did you create the live boot? Did you follow the [documentation?](https://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install)

Comment: Yes, I made a bootable drive from that guide and am also following [this one](https://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-dual-boot-on-mac-hardware)

Comment: Did you try the [Kali Forums](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?29506-Probing-EDD-(edd-off-to-disable))

Comment: I never said that it was hard to set up, or complained about people not helping me. In fact, @RubberStamp that was the answer so if you make it an answer I can ✔️ it

Comment: If you read https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4640/what-should-we-do-about-kali-linux-questions you'll see the relevant context. That question was created as a duplication target for the large amount of bad Kali-related questions that were unclear or lacking in sufficient detail to be answerable. In this case, I disagree with the closure as this question provides enough details to be answerable – and this problem could apply to booting any OS from an image. Accordingly, I’ve nominated this question for re-opening. If 4 other users agree with me, the question will be re-opened.

Comment: *particularly* when an answer has been identified in the comments! 10 hours before the final close vote!

Comment: I edited the question to improve its chances of being re-opened but only 2 users other than myself have voted to re-open the question. It still requires another two users to cast a re-open vote. Unfortunately, it’s been stuck at that vote count for the past few days so it’s not looking promising. :( Better luck with your next question and, for what it’s worth, welcome to [unix.se]!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this thread on Kali Forums](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?29506-Probing-EDD-(edd-off-to-disable))

> Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> at the boot menu. That allows you to edit the kernel command line. Add `edd=off` to the end of the line and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to load it.

As documented in [the kernel’s command-line parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html), this disables the BIOS Enhanced Disk Drive Services (EDD).

See also: [LiveUSB stuck after “Probing EDD” during boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/272701/22812)

Comment: It seems hard to do if connecting on a screenless server with SSH/VNC to create a kvm virtual machine with Kali. I can't connect fast enough to see the boot menu...